# What's the difference between quitting and resigning a job?

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is "resigning" simply more formal than "quitting"?

Here's the case:

> I work for company A but am leaving to work for company B.

Which is better?

> - I work for company A but am quitting to work for company B.
> - I work for company A but am resigning to work for company B.

Comment: He switched a job to company B.

Comment: It depends on the context.  Are you writing to the company; talking to friends; or ... . I'm voting to close this question because there is insufficient information to provide an appropriate answer.

Comment: IMO, "quit his job" is more informal.

Comment: What's wrong with your original choice of "leaving"?

Comment: If you say that you are leaving company A because you have accepted a position with company B, you can avoid the quit/resign conundrum.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it is. From the English Thesaurus, resign is synonym of leave, hand in one's notice, give notice, stand down, step down. And, indicates informal for the following: quit, jump ship.

Based on regular English usage, resign tends to convey a more subtle and amicable separation from your employer whereas quit has a more negative connotation.